# spring-boot strange exceptions when using EnableGlobalMethodSecurity with spring-jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

When I run my app without the @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity annotation it works just fine. However, I want to add support for the @Secured annotation so I would like to add it in. When I do (as shown), I begin to get these exceptions in my tests immediately.

```
@ComponentScan("ltistarter")
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement // enables TX management and @Transaction
@EnableCaching // enables caching and @Cache* tags
@EnableWebMvcSecurity // enable spring security and web mvc hooks
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true) // allows @Secured flag
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
...
```

This Exception (or something like it) appears in my tests and at startup (if I force the tests to skip):

> testJPARelations(ltistarter.ApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
>   <<< ERROR! org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'ltistarter.ApplicationTests': Injection
>   of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: ltistarter.repository.LtiKeyRepository
>   ltistarter.ApplicationTests.ltiKeyRepository; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'ltiKeyRepository': Post-processing of
>   FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not
>   generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88]:
>   Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a
>   non-visible class; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88 ..........

The class it is referring to is here:

```
@Transactional
public interface LtiKeyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<LtiKeyEntity, Long> {
    /**
     * @param key the unique key
     * @return the LtiKeyEntity OR null if there is no entity matching this key
     */
    LtiKeyEntity findByKeyKey(String key);

    /**
     * @param key the unique key
     * @return the number of keys removed (0 or 1)
     */
    int deleteByKeyKey(String key);
}
```

That class is not actually a class, it is an interface as per the spring-boot JPA guide here: http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

I suspect that may be the problem here but if it is, how can I make spring-jpa and spring-security play nice together in spring-boot?

Comment: Try [using aspectj AOP mode](http://gerrydevstory.com/2014/06/28/spring-declarative-transaction-management-with-jdk-proxy-vs-aspectj/) .. or maybe you're annotating invalid items (eg: try annotating real class instead of interface)

Comment: Not following you - I was able to hack around this by removing the proxyTargetClass = true but I am not annotating ANYTHING as Secured yet so I don't think that could be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this by dropping the `proxyTargetClass = true` from `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` like so:

```
@ComponentScan("ltistarter")
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement // enables TX management and @Transaction
@EnableCaching // enables caching and @Cache* tags
@EnableWebMvcSecurity // enable spring security and web mvc hooks
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
// allows @Secured flag - proxyTargetClass = true causes this to die
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
...
```

You can see the code here:

```
https://github.com/azeckoski/lti_starter
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting this issue in Spring Security: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2661. The best workaround for now is to not use JPA for `UserDetailsService` (some would say that `UserDetailsService` is a very simple interface and it doesn't really warrant the use of JPA anyway). You might also be able to rescue the app some other way (e.g. break up the configuration into smaller pieces, use `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter`, don't use `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`, push the security configuration into a parent project).

Update: despite that problem in Spring Security, it *is* still possible to use JPA for user details with `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` (see here for example: https://github.com/scratches/jpa-method-security-sample). So with some tweaking your app can probably work as well.

Comment: It depends - the problem is not really connected to JPA, it's just that using JPA is an easy way to get into trouble. Look at the samples (the one above and the Spring Boot sample ending in "method-security") and try and copy them for the config structure. Or post a link to a minimal project that reproduces the problem and I can take a look.

Comment: This is pretty minimal: https://github.com/azeckoski/lti_starter
I worked around the problem for now by dropping the proxyTargetClass = true but that is just a hack

Comment: That app starts up fine for me. How do I break it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57288/discussion-between-azeckoski-and-dave-syer).